# Java JDBC - ResultSet and encapsulation. Many fields, way too many setters and getters to manage. Is there a better technique?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, encapsulation, setter

I am writing a java program that reads a database file and shows the records on a gui screen, using JDBC and ResultSet. The database file has hundreds of fields. That means that if I separate gui and database processing in two class files and use encapsulation, I’d end up with hundreds of setter and getter methods (one for each field). Is there a better way of doing this?

Note that I have used setters and getters for this purpose and found out that it can get really hard to manage. I also have seen articles that advocate avoiding to use setters and getters altogether but did not find a concrete example of such technique for database management.

Thanks I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you have hundreds of columns in your database table?  Does it need to be normalised?

Comment: If the table literally has "hundreds of fields" then someone really screwed up when designing the database.

Comment: If you can't change the schema, at least don't map the table to a unique Java class. I'm sure some columns should be grouped inside a different class (like User - Address ...)

Comment: Have you considered using Hibernate?

Comment: Wow! Great turn out. Thanks for all your input. I'll go thru all suggestions in detail as soon as I can. For now I'll just add that I did not design the database and cannot change the original file (it comes from an IBM as400 machine -Cobol/RPG languages). Also all fields in the file are needed and there are a lot of records. Breaking the file in smaller ones would bring performance issues because JDBC seems to take longer to open different files than to read one big file. Wouldn't creating new classes have the same issue of having to manage too many setters and getters (in different classes)?

Comment: @DavidWallace because it may be a legacy database from late 80-90 years (usually built on IBM AS-400 or Informix) that must be maintained and doesn't have any normalization rules. For example, I had to maintain an application against a Customer table where the customer could have until 10 kids (very big families around here) so for each kid there was at least 4 fields (really bad design but cannot be changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to just store each row into a `Map`.

To do this, you can retrieve the column names using `ResultSetMetaData` (key = column name) or you can just retrieve the column values using the column index (key = index). `ResultSet` can deal with it both ways.

Then, your result will look like a `List<Map>` structure.

Comment: Interesting. Let me see if I understand. I would load the ResultSet into a Map (which is private), create a setter and a getter for that Map and access the data using the column index (key = index) in the other class? Thanks for your answer BTW.

Comment: @user3618243 do this and it will work *fine* first, then fight with the future maintenance problems. A better option is using an ORM framework that ease these problems.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza of course an ORM is better for maintenance, but I am assuming here that the user has a table with hundreds of columns, probably generated by some ERP (so it's not his/her fault it's not normalized - maybe he/she just can't fix this). With hundreds of columns, I don't really think it makes THAT MUCH difference if you have 200 getters + setters because no one will write 100 getters, everyone will use reflection instead. Map will just work in the same way without reflection overhead.

Comment: You can write your own column mappers in jpa to ease this and have few getter/setters for these columns. Besides, I already worked with this both approaches and using hundred of getters/setters was way better than using the Map approach by far.

Comment: I agree with you that generating JPA beans will provide type safety, because you have 1 type per column. Except for that, he/she will have to iterate on the columns via reflection. For more complex apps / if this is gonna be used in several places, ORM may be the way to go. But if he/she just wants a quick and dirty solution just to grab the data from the DB once, for a few and localized usage, I think the Map is good enough. Again, the question was about how to avoid getters and setters. For me, he/she can use map or interleave the bytecodes to generate these getters on compilation time.

Comment: I am going thru all suggestions and will respond as soon as possible. I'll just ad that I did not design the database and cannot change the original file (it comes from an IBM as400 machine -Cobol/RPG languages). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, if your DB literally has hundreds of fields then something went wrong during the design.

In that case what i would do / advise is - try to categorize whatever is in your database. So for example imagine you have these columns

```
ID | FirstName | MiddleName | Surname | Gender | Age | HairColor | EyeColor | BuildingNO | StreetName | City | State | PostCode | Country | CarMake | CarPlate | etc...
```

I would create a class for Person, Address, Car and put queries in these classes that will extract info from database relevant to this particular object.

so in Person class i would have something like this

```
public class Person {
   private FirstName;
   private MiddleName;
   private Surname; 

   appropriate query here and plug the whole object into a list - so you will end up with a List of Objects 'Person' with relevant data in it. 
   /* Setters and Getters */
```

same for the other class Address

```
public class Address {


public class Car {
```

Hopefully you get what i mean

Comment: That was my first impulse and I did try some similar. Everything looked fine until I got hit with the performance problem. JDBC, at least in this case (JDBC.as400), takes a lot longer to access a file (open/clsoe) than it does to read it. Having several classes accessing the file multiple times would result in the loading time not being acceptable. If you consider running on the web or over a VPN, forget about it. Having several classes would also mean having to manage not only the setters and getters but also the classes themselves. I'd be fine with that if it wasn't for performance. Thanks!.

Comment: @Gil hmm well in that case, if you can't split that maybe what you can do ( but its gonna be very dirty solution, is to omit setters and getters - write one big query and extract all fields from DB in one go into simple variables

Answer (score 0):

I’ve implemented the Map strategy as suggested by Leo. Thought it’s not a unanimous solution, it is something I can use immediately and I do think it is a pretty good alternative. It not only allows the elimination of excessive setters and getters but you can also create ArrayList’s (or any other collection) to hold each field dynamically. There’s no need to know the instance name of each list because you can access them by the Map’s key (key = column name), therefore avoiding the need to code a list for each field. I truly think this is a major advantage. Then it’s possible to iterate each field straight to a string (or any other type) making the code leaner.

For example:

Class LoadBigFile connects to the database and loads the file’s contents to a map.

Something like this (please note: this is just a very vague example to illustrate what can be done):

```
    Class LoadBigFile{

       private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> filemap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

       ////// ...Code to connect to database and load the file contents into the map

       ////// Setter and getter for the map:

       public void setFileMap(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> filemap){this.filemap=filemap;}
       public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getFileMap(){return this.filemap;}

    }
```

Then in the class you’re going use the data (unpack the map):

```
      LoadBigFile loadBigFile = new LoadBigFile();
      String customer = loadBigFile.getFileMap().get("CUSTOMER").get(iterator));
```

NOTE: I will not go over the iterator because it would be off topic. All I can say is that it works.

Even thought I am still looking into other techniques such as ORM and JPA, I’ll try the map approach as I develop my skills and learn more sophisticated methods.

Thank you all. I hope this question helps other java enthusiasts out there.